# Как запретить нажимать кнопку более 1 раза?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<button class="btn blue rounded" onclick="LetsGo();">Открыть бесплатно</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно добавить флаг какой-нибудь, например так:

```
var isClicked = false;
```

А в функции LetsGo() сделать проверку

```
function LetsGo(){
    if (isClicked)  //проверка флага
        return;
    isClicked = true; // при первом проходе проверка не пройдет и флаг изменит значение
    document.getElementById("ButtonID").disabled = true; //Для кнопки лучше задать ID, так легче ее найти
    ... // Тело вашей функции
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Никак.

Заблокируете кнопку, я перезагружу страницу и нажму. Сохраните меня в local storage или куку, я почищу и все равно нажму.

Единственно - спрятать кнопку под авторизацию, и проверять в бэкенде, какой пользователь кликал кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - добавить в вашу функцию обработку - если есть класс 'clicked' - то возвращать false, иначе навешиваем этот класс и далее уже всё остальное от функции

Answer (score 1):

Еще проще:

```
<button class="btn blue rounded" onclick="LetsGo();this.setAttribute('onclick', '');">Открыть бесплатно</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

В функции LetsGo() первым же действием прописать для элемента свойство disabled. 
document.getElementsByClassName("btn").disabled = true;

Рекомендую дать кнопке имя или id, чтобы однозначно идентифицировать её в документе